# is there any use for GCC -S flag with gcc -c

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I wonder if there is any benefit for using the `-S` GCC option in my Makefiles.

I've been compiling C files like the following for quite some time now:

```
gcc -c a.c -o a.o
gcc -c b.c -o b.o
---
gcc a.o b.o -o a.out
```

Now would it be better going:

```
gcc -S a.c -o a.s
gcc -S b.c -o b.s
---
gcc -c a.s -o a.o
gcc -c b.s -o b.o
---
gcc a.o b.o -o a.out
```

Also there is apparently the option of skipping the `.o` phase, assembling directly `.s` files into a binary. Which option you think is the best and why?

Comment: Why would you want assembler-code as an intermediate stage? In most cases one does not care about the actual assembly code.

Comment: Do you want to examine the generated assembler code for some reason?

Comment: Not really, I guess there's no point then

Comment: You can also skip `.s` and `.o` entirely by calling `gcc a.c b.c -o a.out`. The intermediate object files are useful for example if your build process needs them more than once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-S` flags asks gcc to produce human readable assembly code - .o files are nice for a linker but rather cryptic for most human beings...

It is mainly used when you need low level optimization of a (short) piece of code that has been identified by profiling as being a bottleneck. You can compare how the compiler will translate various versions and choose the one that will give the most efficient machine code *for that specific implementation*.

It is not intended to be used in standard makefiles.

Answer (score 1):

> Also there is apparently the option of skipping the `.o` phase, assembling directly `.s` files into a binary.

Plain assembly is never transformed directly to executable binary code, there is always in intermediate object-file step.

```
gcc a.s b.s -o ab.exe
```

will always call the assembler (twice) which produces object code for either units, and then the objects are linked. Add `-v` to the command line to see which sub-commands are executed by `gcc`. `gcc` is not actually a compiler, it is just a driver program calling jobs depending on options and file extensions.  The compiler proper is `cc1` (for C code), `cc1plus` (for C++ code), etc.

> Which option you think is the best and why?

`-S` has the advantage to producing assembly code, however the compiler will *always* generate assembly code as intermediate step.  It's just the case that it's written to temporary files, with 2 notable exceptions:

- `-save-temps`: This will not use some temporary-file names (for example in `/tmp`), but save the intermediate code in the same place as the objects (there are two flavors actually, `-save-temps=obj` and `-save-temps=src`).
- `-pipe`: This will used pipes to transfer code from one sup-program to the next instead of files (except with `-save-temps` which nullifies `-pipe`).

Thus, if you want to see the generated assembly, `-save-temps` might be the way to go.  However, that option also applies to the pre-processed code which is saved in `.i` for C, `.ii` for C++ and `.s` for assembly.  This is often very appreciated when working with C macros.

In the case you intend to inspect the compiler-generated assembly, you might enjoy `-fverbose-asm` which injects asm comments that indicate the C/C++ source associated to the assembly.  And it might be a good idea not to clutter assembly with debug-info in that case.